# What're the advantages of having Node (Express) start up the Webpack dev server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've been reading through Webpack's documentation and having a little bit of a hard time understanding what are the advantages of having your backend server (Node in this instance) start up the Webpack dev server.

It seems to make the code more complicated, when you can simply run them separately anyways and have them speak to one another?

Comment: Where in the documentation does it talk about having your backend server start up webpack-dev-server? As far as I can tell, the two recommended options are 1) to use your backend as a [proxy](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy), or 2) [some complicated thing](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#combining-with-an-existing-server) I haven't tried. But both of these involve having two separate servers running. Do you mean, What are the advantages of option 2 over option 1?

Comment: Yeah, exactly... I'm trying to figure out the advantages of option 2, as I'm having Node serve an API for the front end to consume.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But unfortunately your guess is as good as mine. I also wondered what the benefit would be, since the proxy option just seems so much simpler. Hopefully someone on here knows the answer.

Comment: I got the more complicated one to work, thankfully, but haven't gone through with the simpler one. By chance, do you have reference to a good working example explaining this? I'd like to give it a try to see if it simplifies the code.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538472/webpack-dev-server-with-backend-api/35539631#35539631). I don't know if it's actually that much simpler; it may just be that I haven't tried the other option.